# proof of bd (mod n) need help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Show that if $a \equiv b$ (mod $n$) and $c \equiv d$ (mod $n$), then $a + c \equiv b + d$ (mod $n$) and $ac \equiv bd$ (mod $n$).

I'm new to discrete. So far I have

Proof

$a \equiv b $(mod $u$) $\Leftrightarrow a = k \cdot n + b$ 
$c \equiv d $(mod $u$) $\Leftrightarrow c = k \cdot n + d$ 
$a+c=(kn+b)+(ln+d)=(k+l)n+b+d$ 
$ac=(kn+b)(ln+d)=?$

I'm not seeing how to manipulate to get the correct form $bd$ (mod $n$)

EDIT: Solved in comments. Thank you for the help

$ac=(kn+b)(ln+d)=(kln+kd+bl)n+bd$

Comment: $(kn+b)(ln+d)=(kln+kd+bl)n+bd$

Comment: thank you! this makes sense I was close in desmos my brain must be fried. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

$$
ac=(kn+b)(ln+d) = kln^2 + n(dk+bl) + bd
$$
Now what is $ac \pmod{n}$?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively.

$a\equiv b \pmod n \iff n|a-b$.

We have $n|a-b$ and $n|c-d$ so

$n|(a-b)+(c-d) = (a+c) -(b+d)$ so $a+c \equiv b+d \pmod n$.

And $ac - bd =ac - ad + ad - bd = (ac-ad) + (ad -bd) = a(c-d) + d(a-b)$.

And we have $n|c-d$ and $n|a-b$ so $n|a(c-d) + d(a-b) = ac - bd$.  So $ac \equiv bd \pmod n$.